# Force webview to open new browser window or google play store

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, webview

Right now, I am using webview to promote one of our website from within the app. It's linked to a PHP file which is rotating links based on geos. When i try to link to a google play app with market://link, it doesn't work.

I tried to then create a HTML page and then put a google play button for users to click on to open play store. That didn't work either. It just opens within the webview and show standard message, "this browser is no longer supproted"

Is there any way, i can resolve this without updating my app? Anything I can do in my HTML or PHP file I am linking from the webview?

Comment: <?php
$url='market://details?id=<package_name>"';
header("Location:$url");
exit();
?>